# Does NodeJS's "https" library support DNS failover?

Tags: node.js, https, dns

Let us say I am doing an HTTP GET request to the host which's DNS record contains multiple IP addresses, for example `twitter.com`:

```
twitter.com.        45  IN  A   104.244.42.1
twitter.com.        45  IN  A   104.244.42.65
```

Let us suppose one of this IP addresses is not available due to some reasons (for example outgoing connection is blocked on the firewall).

Will `https.get()` try all of these IP addresses from the DNS query results or only one of them?

```
var https = require('https');

https.get('https://www.twitter.com', function(res) { ... }
```

I've performed a sample test with blocking one of these addresses and it seems that **it does not perform** a retry to another IP address when the first one tried is unavailable. But because of lack of debug logs I am not 100% confident. Can some confirm this assumption or disprove it instead *based on the source code of the library or on the official documentation*?

---

```
]$ dig twitter.com

...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
twitter.com.        60  IN  A   104.244.42.1
twitter.com.        60  IN  A   104.244.42.193
```

`104.244.42.193` is blocked in the firewall

```
]$ node failovertest.js 
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.244.42.193:443
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16) {
  errno: -110,
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '104.244.42.193',
  port: 443
}
```

Comment: "Will https.get() try all of these IP addresses from the DNS query results or only one of them?" That should be covered in the library documentation, but typically, probably NO. Clients such as browsers typically might do multiple IP addresses try (including both IPv4 and IPv6 and picking the fastest one)